# How do i execute part of a shell script every 5 minutes and anothe rpart every 1 hour?

Tags: bash

I have a shell script that collects some data and send it to destination. Part of the data should be copied every 5 minutes and other every 20 minutes. How can this be achieved in a single script? As of now i'm collecting the data every 5 minutes by scheduling with cron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice would be to use to separate files with two different `cron` entries. If you need to reutilize part of your code consider using functions.

If you still want to do it in only one file, you should run it every 5 minutes and on each run check whether or not you should execute the other part (every 20 min) or not.

```
modulo=$((`date +%_M)` % 20))
//do whatever has to be done every 5min
[...]
//check for modulo of current minute / 20
if [ $modulo -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo Current minute is `date +%_M)`, must execute part 2
    //whatever has to be done every 20min
else 
    //do nothing
fi;
```

The reason why the variable `modulo` is defined in the first line is because what has to be done every 5min can potentially take longer than 1min to execute so by the time it is done minute is no longer 20 but 21. Defining the variable before is a safeguard to overcome this.

Comment: I just noticed your question text says "every 20 minutes" and the title says "every one hour". To run a part every one hour it'd be the same but replacing "20" with "0".

Comment: Thanks, this serves my purpose.

Comment: have to be careful when the minute is `08` or `09` -- bash will give you an arithmetic error because you have a invalid octal number. Either force base 10 with `$(( 10#$(date +%M) % 60 ))` or get date to return the minute without a leading zero `$(( $(date +%_M) % 60 ))`